# What is the different between unity engine code and unity script code?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't understand the exact meaning of the different between unity engine and the unity code. Can anyone please clear this?

[image]

Comment: I am a little confused as to what your question is. What do you mean by `Unity Engine Code` and `Unity Script Code`? Are you asking the difference between something like `using UnityEngine.UI` and the engine itself?

Comment: I would think Unity Engine code is part of what Unity provide for you, and that Unity Script Code (presumably not to be confused with the deprecated UnityScript scripting language - now replaced with C#) refers to scripts you write? I could be wrong though.

Comment: @TEEBQNE I added the screenshot with that question now

Comment: @Llama I agree with your answer but in unity manual they provide both codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two different [`namespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace)s.

As the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/) states itself

> API are grouped by namespaces they belong to, and can be selected from the sidebar to the left. **For most users, the `UnityEngine` section will be the main port of call.**

- `UnityEngine` basically contains all Unity **runtime** related API. This is as said **the main part** where you will move in since this contains basically all Unity built-in types that are relevant for a built application.
- [`UnityEditor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UnityEditor.html)

  > The `UnityEditor` assembly implements the editor-specific APIs in Unity. It cannot be referenced by runtime code compiled into players.

  as the name suggests are additional functionalities and libraries which only make sense inside the editor itself. They are mainly part of the [Editor GUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingTheEditor.html) itself (Hierarchy, SceneView, GameView, Inspector, etc) and for **enhancing these** by implementing own [`CustomEditor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html)s or [`EditorWindow`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.html)s

  **This namespace will be completely stripped of during the build process** since as said it only makes sense inside the Editor itself.

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, you want clarification as to what `UnityEngine` and `UnityEditor` are. It is quite simple actually. Anything that falls under `UnityEngine` can be used in the Editor or in a build, while anything in `UnityEditor` can **only** be used in the Editor. They are just two different namespaces that categorize where functions can be used.

Meaning whenever you want to build your game, nothing using the `UnityEditor` include will work. Think of any functions in the `UnityEditor` namespace as tools that can be used in the Editor to help you create your game. Once the game leaves the Editor though, whatever functionality you had will no longer work as it is only intended to be used in the Editor.

Comment: I fixed some typos, I think now it should be less confusing ;)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, UnityEngine is a library that allows you to use unity functions and modules. UnityEditor allow you to use the editor functions, these functions don't work on builds.

Answer (score -1):

Unity Engine use to support 3 Languages, C#, Python (Boo) and Java Script (***Unity Script***). So Unity Script is actually a part of the Unity Code suit (.NET Framework 2).

But these days Unity only uses C# when it switched to .NET Framework 4.8. When looking for solutions ensure to not look at any Unity Script code as it is outdated.

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: unity editor and the unity script are the same?

Comment: @TPath Not quite. This answer is not wrong, but not quite what you are looking for from your updated post. `UnityScript` is a programming language that was an alternative to `C#` when programming with Unity. It was a variant somewhat of `Javascript`. All current and future versions of Unity just use `C#` though.

Comment: Unity Editor is the program `Unity`. Unity Script is one of the programming language you use in the scripts.

Comment: `UnityEgnine` - Is the Code Used to run your game. When you click Run/Play the program uses the Unity Engine to run. When you create your game, you use the Unity Editor to create your game.

Comment: @user15119845 and @ TEEBQNE Thank you for your explanation in Unity Script

Comment: @user15119845 I thing your answer is little clear for me.